# Rendering multiple plots stored in a list in R shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to render the bar plots stored in "Plotlist" through the shiny app. I am new to Shiny and request help regarding it. The code:

```
o<-list()
for(i in 1:10){
  Z3<-seq(1+i,10+i,1)
  o<-append(o,list(Z3))
}

Plotlist <- vector(mode = "list", 10)
for(i in 1:10){
  s<-barplot(o[[i]],names.arg = paste("A",1:10,sep = "_"),main=paste("Plot",i)) 
  Plotlist[[i]]<-recordPlot()
}

library(shiny)

ui<-fluidPage(titlePanel("Plots in a list"),
              sidebarPanel(selectInput("plot", "Choose Plot:", choices=paste("Plot",1:10)),hr(),helpText("Trial Plots"),
                           mainPanel(plotOutput("BARPLOT"))))  
server<-function(input, output) {
  output$BARPLOT<-renderPlot(for(i in 1:10){Plotlist[[i]]})
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to print the specified plot you need access the selected value of `selectinput` inside the `renderplot` this is done by adding `{i<-input$plot}` where plot is the name of the input

```r
choices = 1:10

names(choices) <- paste("Plot",1:10)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Plots in a list"),
        sidebarPanel(
   selectInput("plot", "Choose Plot:", choices=choices),
   hr(),
   helpText("Trial Plots")),
    plotOutput("barplot")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
     output$barplot<-renderPlot({
         i<- as.integer(input$plot)
         barplot(o[[i]],names.arg = paste("A",1:10,sep = "_"),main=paste("Plot",i)) 
     },  width=400) 
  }
)
```

Comment: you can save the data into a list and then generate the plot

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution, Thank you Abdessabour Mtk

```
choices = 1:10

names(choices) <- paste("Plot",1:10)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Plots in a list"),
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("plot", "Choose plot:", choices=choices),
      hr(),
      helpText("Trail plots")),
    plotOutput("barplot")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$barplot<-renderPlot({
      i<- as.integer(input$plot)
      Plotlist[[i]]
    })
  }
)
```